# How to get data from Firebase when I click on 1 of 3 makers on the Map

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

When I click on 1 of 3 random `Marker`s, it always shows me `name: IJKL` or last data in **Firebase**. How can I get data when I click 1 of 3 random markers and show the data in a `Toast`?

Example data structure in **Firebase**:

```
Name_Data :
     -asdejnwiqbersad
        name : ABCD

     -asldmlmlwqkrioi
        name : EFGH

     -asldmlmlwqkrioi
        name : IJKL
```

Here is how I show the data:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
          Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is how I put those 3 `Marker`s on the Map:

```
refDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            LatLng newlocation = new LatLng(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class),dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class));
            name = new String(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));             
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newlocation).title(name));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use [`Marker#getTitle()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#getTitle()):**

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return false;
    }
});
```

Because you added a name to the marker via:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newlocation).title(name));
//                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @husen You're welcome :) Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this.

If you want to get the Name for particular Marker then firstly you want to get know that which marker is clicked like Position and when you get the position then definitely you get the correct name on marker click.
Here is the method to get the position

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
      // position of clicked marker
      int position = Integer.parseInt(marker.getId().replace("m", ""));
      //Now you can get the name from Name_Data using this position
      Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, get name like this ...

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
      Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,marker.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That's the same as my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511338) that was posted 3 minutes ago.